# Starting executables in alternate data streams

Tags: windows-7, windows, alternate-data-stream

I've read an article on this topic, and I know running executables from Alternate Data Streams (ADS) is disabled in Windows 7. Is there any alternate way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, actually there is a way.

[Creating a symbolic link to an executable](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2012/04/ultimate-guide-manipulating-alternate-data-streams/) held in an ADS will allow you to call the link and run the file. For example, if I had an executable called `some_exe.exe` in a ADS of `some_file.txt` I could create a link like so:

```
mklink some_name.exe some_file:some_exe.exe
```

I can then call `some_name.exe` to run the executable contained in `some_file.txt`.

Answer (score -1):

Symbolic links don't work for exe's created from ADS, what works is:

```
expand some_file:some_exe.exe some_name.exe
```

Script files will run inside ADS directly.